# How to execute a constructor more than once without page refresh

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am new in using `OOP` methodology in `javascript`, I use the following code below as a `constructor`.

```
var post = function post() {}
```

I call the constructor inside a `jQuery` event handler

```
post = new post();
```

At first run or on each page refresh, it works well because a `method` `invocation` after calling the `constructor` gets executed. But on clicking the button that triggers the event the second time, it would not execute anymore, I instead get the following error message in `firebug`

```
TypeError: post is not a constructor
```

So why does it not work again after the first run, without a page refresh?

And how will I make it work continuously without page refresh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why does it not work again after the first run

Because you've overwritten the `post` symbol. This line:

```
post = new post();
```

Calls your `post` constructor and assigns the resulting object to the `post` variable. Now `post` isn't a constructor function anymore, it's the object created via `new post`.

Just use a different name:

```
var p = new post();
```

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions start with an initial upper case letter, e.g. `Post` rather than `post`. You're free to ignore that convention, but it may make it difficult for others to read your code (for instance, here on SO).

Comment: How did you answer so fast? :)

Comment: @user1436026: Simple question, and I took typing in high school. ;-)

Comment: *Sidenote:* `var post = function post(){}` also has confusing side-effects, since the `post` reference is no longer the named function expression.

Comment: @David your point is not so clear to me, but how should it be done right? Thanks.